# When using Linear Discriminant Analysis and k nearest neighbours in classification, which is better?

Tags: classification, k-nearest-neighbour

I am currently performing classification on the Iris dataset. I used both LDA and kNN methods to classify the data. I found both to be highly accurate and cannot decide which one is more appropriate to use? My first thought is kNN since LDA assumes the data to have a multivariate normal distribution. However, would love to know more theory behind which is better. I have included my decision boundary plots of each classifier as I am not sure which boundary is better?
[image: kNN classifier]

[image: LDA classifier]